# VHDL: Create finite state machine from logic expressions

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I've been asked to create a finite state machine using one-hot encoding that will detect a sequence of four 1's or 0's on the input w. I've already written the code using case statements, but I have to also have to do it by providing the logic expressions as inputs to 9 flip flops. I'm not getting the correct output on z, and I can't quite figure out why.

So far I've written the following code for a D flip flop

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dflipflop is
    port (D, clk, reset: in std_logic;
        Q: out std_logic);
end dflipflop;

architecture behavior of dflipflop is
begin
process(clk)
begin
    if reset <= '0' then 
        Q <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        Q <= D;
    end if;
end process;
end behavior;
```

Then I have this as the rest of my code, which is where I believe the problem lies.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity part1 is 
port (clk, w, reset : in std_logic;
        z: out std_logic);
end part1;

architecture behavior of part1 is
    component dflipflop 
    port (D, clk, reset: in std_logic; 
            Q: out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I: std_logic;
    signal Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5, Y6, Y7, Y8, Y9: std_logic;

   dff1: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y1, Q=>A);
   dff2: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y2, Q=>B);
   dff3: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y3, Q=>C);
   dff4: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y4, Q=>D);
   dff5: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y5, Q=>E);
   dff6: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y6, Q=>F);
   dff7: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y7, Q=>G);
   dff8: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y8, Q=>H);
   dff9: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset, D=>Y9, Q=>I);

begin
process(clk);
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
    Y1 <= (((not w) and C) or ((not w) and G) or ((not w) and H) or ((not w) and I) or (w and B) or (w and D) or (w and E) or (w and F));
    Y2 <= ((not w) and A);
    Y3 <= (w and A);
    Y4 <= ((not w) and B);
    Y5 <= ((not w) and D);
    Y6 <= (((not w) and E) or ((not w) and F));
    Y7 <= (w and C);
    Y8 <= (w and G);
    Y9 <= ((w and H) or (w and I));
end if;
end process;
z <= (Y6 OR Y9);

end behavior;
```

Can anyone provide any hints or insight as to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I could be a cut and past error... But the instantiations of the dflipflop component has to be below the `begin`...

Comment: and the `;` after the `process(clk) should not be there

Comment: <rant>Why are teachers (I assume) still setting this daft sort of task with artificial constraints?</rant> Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

### Initial remarks (looking at your source code):

- Your **dflipflop** description seems fine, although I don't see any reason for using an asynchronous reset. Consider changing it to a [synchronous reset flip-flop](http://www.asic-world.com/code/vhdl_examples/dff_sync_reset.vhd) unless your design realy requires some FF  to asynchronously reset.
- You've placed your combinatorial logic sentences inside a clocked process. Now, if you are to instantiating the flip flops structurally, all those sentences shouldn't be inside one, since they are already being clocked by the flip-flops.
- You should use signal names more wisely, otherwise your code will very hard to read and debug, particularly for more complex designs. Also, use `reset= '1'` or `reset='0'` for readability, instead of `reset <='0'`, if you want active high or active low reset, respectively.

### How would I do it:

I believe you are looking for a structural description of a simple Finite-state machine (FSM) for a bit detector with the following graphical representation, and a total of 9 states. One-hot encoding means you need to assign one Flip-flop per state. [image]

First, declare 9 std_logic signals,  where each one represents one state in
 a one hot-enconded FSM. These will be the output signals of the 9
 FFs:

```
 signal init : std_logic;  -- Initial/reset state            
 signal zeros_1 : std_logic;  -- 1 zero  detected
 signal zeros_2 : std_logic;  -- 2 zeros detected
 signal zeros_3 : std_logic;  -- 3 zeros detected
 signal zeros_4 : std_logic;  -- 4 zeros detected
 signal ones_1  : std_logic;  -- 1 one   detected
 signal ones_2  : std_logic;  -- 1 one   detected
 signal ones_3  : std_logic;  -- 1 one   detected
 signal ones_4  : std_logic;  -- 1 one   detected
```

Declare extra 9 std_logic signals, to hold the next value for the
    corresponding state Flip Flop. These will be the input signals for
    the 9 FFs:

```
 signal go_to_init   : std_logic;
 signal go_to_zeros_1 : std_logic;  
 signal go_to_zeros_2 : std_logic;  
 signal go_to_zeros_3 : std_logic;  
 signal go_to_zeros_4 : std_logic;  
 signal go_to_ones_1  : std_logic;  
 signal go_to_ones_2  : std_logic;  
 signal go_to_ones_3  : std_logic;  
 signal go_to_ones_4  : std_logic;
```

Map the 9 Flip-flops to the corresponding signals.

Note that if you want initialize the state machine with the RESET signal you will need a D Flip-flop which is HIGH on RESET. You can use the description of **dflipflop**, change `if reset='1' then Q <='0'` to  `if reset='1' then Q <='1'` and use it to implement the new **dflipflop_RH**.

```
init_ff   : dflipflop_RH port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_init, Q=> init);
zeros_1_ff: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_zeros_1, Q=> zeros_1 );
zeros_2_ff: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_zeros_2, Q=> zeros_2 );
zeros_3_ff: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_zeros_3, Q=> zeros_3 );
zeros_4_ff: dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_zeros_4, Q=> zeros_4 );
ones_1_ff : dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_ones_1, Q=> ones_1 );
ones_2_ff : dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_ones_2, Q=> ones_2 );
ones_3_ff : dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_ones_3, Q=> ones_3 );
ones_4_ff : dflipflop port map (clk=>clk, reset=>reset,D=> go_to_ones_4, Q=> ones_4 );
```

Finally, add the combinatorial logic to compute the next state from the current state and the input signal 'w'. Since it is a very simple FSM, you just need to translate the FSM graphical representation into VHDL code:

```
 go_to_init <= '0';  -- never go to init (only when reset='1') 

 go_to_zeros_1 <= (init or ones_1 or ones_2 or ones_3 or ones_4  ) and (not w);
 go_to_zeros_2 <= zeros_1 and (not w);
 go_to_zeros_3 <= zeros_2 and (not w);
 go_to_zeros_4 <= (zeros_3 or zeros_4) and (not w);

 go_to_ones_1 <= (init or zeros_1 or zeros_2 or zeros_3 or zeros_4) and w;
 go_to_ones_2 <= ones_1 and w;
 go_to_ones_3 <= ones_2 and w;
 go_to_ones_4 <= (ones_3 or ones_4) and w;

 z <= ones_4 or zeros_4;
```

Answer (score 0):

After reset, all outputs of the dflipflops are at '0'.

```
if reset <= '0' then 
    Q <= '0';
```

So, A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H and I are at '0'.

Due to the Boolean logic to assign the Yn signals, the Yn will always be at '0'.

E.g.

```
Y2 <= ((not w) and A); -- A is at '0' => Y2 will always be '0'.
```

The output 'z' will always be '0':

```
z <= (Y6 OR Y9); -- Y6 is always '0', Y9 is always '0' => Z will always be '0'.
```

By the way: it's a good design rule to register the outputs of a component.  I would place the `z <= (Y6 OR Y9);` inside the process.

Could it be the output of dflipflop must be '1' under reset?

Answer (score 0):

I would write much more readable code for such a small task:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity part1 is 
port (
    clk     : in  std_logic;
    w       : in  std_logic;
    reset_n : in  std_logic; -- mark low active signals with suffix _n
    z       : out std_logic
);
end part1;

architecture rtl of part1 is
     signal sreg : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
     process
     begin
         wait until rising_edge( clk);

         -- shift register
         sreg <= sreg(2 downto 0) & w;

         if sreg = "0000" or sreg = "1111" then
             z <= '1';
         else
             z <= '0';
         end if;

         -- do we really need a reset?
         if reset_n = '0' then
             sreg <= "0000";
         end if;
     end process;
end architecture rtl;
```